# Vue spread an object as computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vue-cli, spread-syntax

I have an array of objects called `config`, and a `currentIdx` property in my component. Then I found myself needing to do this:

```
computed: {
    textStyle: function() {
        return this.config[this.currentIdx].textStyle;
    },
    text: function() {
        return this.config[this.currentIdx].text;
    },
    key: function() {
        return this.config[this.currentIdx].key;
    }
}
```

I tried replacing all functions with:

```
computed: {
    ...this.config[this.currentIdx]
}
```

It passed the compilation, but I got an error in the browser console. I think the problem is that `computed` requires functions, but the spread syntax (...) returns objects. So, my question is: **Is there any way to reduce the repetition in this case?**

Thanks!

Comment: you could create a wrapping helper that will take in an object, and return a new object that has the same keynames mapped to a function that returns that key value, though I'm unsure how well that will play with the computed nature.

Comment: The computed property definitions cannot be aware of your component instance since they are created at compilation time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Computed values can return objects, they just need to be returned by the function.  Let me know if this isn't what you intended and I'll see what I can do to help!

```js
let vm = new Vue({
  el : "#root",
  data : {
    current : 0,
    arrs : [
      {
        color : "background-color: blue;",
        text : "Dabodee Dabodai"
      },
      {
        color : "background-color: red;",
        text : "Angry"
      },
      {
        color : "background-color: green;",
        text : "See it works!"
      }
    ]
  },
  computed : {
    currentObject : function() {
      return this.arrs[this.current];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <input type="number" v-model="current" min="0" max="2">
  <p :style="currentObject.color">
    {{ currentObject.text }}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah , but I still need to type `currentObject` every time I want to use it. Is it possible to directly declare the properties under the component, and use it like: `<p :style="color">` rather than `<p :style="currentObject.color">`?

Comment: Afaik not with pure Vue.js and JS.  Maybe with Vuex or another combination of libraries. @Bennet Hardwick's answer does it in vanilla JS but losing the "currentObject" may make your code less clear.  Good luck either way!

Comment: Yeah you are right, keeping a `currentObject` may protect the namespace, so I will probably go with that.

Comment: You could make a computed for `color` if you wanted that. It would just `return currentObject.color`

Comment: @RoyJ Yes you are right. But if I have a bunch of attributes in `currentObject`, I would have to create those computed values one by one, which is kind of repetitive...